# Why scp with compression takes longer than without compression

Tags: performance, scp, compression

I was playing around and noticed that secure-copying with compression takes longer than without compression

```
time scp -C ./test.sql user@vmware:/home/user

real    0m42.758s
user    0m40.455s
sys     0m2.159s
```

and

```
time scp ./test.sql user@vmware:/home/user

real    0m11.117s
user    0m2.827s
sys     0m2.157s
```

What could be the cause of this behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compression and decompression take time, so it's a trade off. If you have a slow network connection, it's worth taking the time for compression. If you have a 1Gbps connection between two nodes, you're probably going to lose more time to compression than you'll gain from transferring less data.

Comment: I would add : the 'vmware' server name let me think he's on a local virtualized machine. I don't know precisely how network hardware is involved and limited, but what is certain is that if you scp to a local virtual machine, you should have a really, really good transfer rate... ;)

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierVares you are right, that is a virtual machine. I explicitly specified that :)